# Understanding TLS arragement for FTP project: ftp-srv in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, ftp, tls1.2

I am trying to understand how TLS can be set up accurately for my FTP project (typescript, nodejs) based on this API:
[ftp-srv](https://github.com/QuorumDMS/ftp-srv)

The documentation there is very basic. In one of the related github issues of the project, the author points to his source code / test example - [here](https://github.com/QuorumDMS/ftp-srv/blob/main/test/index.spec.js#L25)

In that example is a section:

```
  describe('#EXPLICIT', function () {
    before(() => {
      return server.close()
      .then(() => Promise.all([
        readFile(`${process.cwd()}/test/cert/server.key`),
        readFile(`${process.cwd()}/test/cert/server.crt`),
        readFile(`${process.cwd()}/test/cert/server.csr`)
      ]))
      .then(([key, cert, ca]) => startServer({
        url: 'ftp://127.0.0.1:8881',
        tls: {key, cert, ca}
      }))
      .then(() => {
        return connectClient({
          secure: true,
          secureOptions: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            checkServerIdentity: () => undefined
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

From this example I can read that a programmer can create references to 3 crypto files:

```
 - ../server.key

 - ../server.crt

 - ../server.csr
```

than, to read these files and direct their output to a tls object e.g:

```
const tls: SecureContextOptions = {
  key:    <-- readFile('server.key'),
  cert:   <-- readFile('server.crt'),
  ca:     <-- readFile('server.csr'),
}
```

If this is right (correct me if wrong), I need the understanding of what the 3 files represent from the prospective of TLS.

TLS for NodeJS documentation is pretty clear - [here](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls-ssl)

Following this documentation we create 5 (five) SSL crypto files:

```
file 1:  ryans-key.pem    <--- by command:  openssl genrsa -out ryans-key.pem 2048
file 2:  ryans-csr.pem    <--- by command:  openssl req -new -sha256 -key ryans-key.pem -out ryans-csr.pem
file 3:  ryans-cert.pem   <--- by command:  openssl x509 -req -in ryans-csr.pem -signkey ryans-key.pem -out ryans-cert.pem
file 4:  ca-cert.pem      <--- by command:  cat ryans-cert.pem > ca-cert.pem
file 5:  ryans.pfx        <--- by command:  openssl pkcs12 -export -in ryans-cert.pem -inkey ryans-key.pem -certfile ca-cert.pem -out ryans.pfx
```

Now, which of these five crypto files go to which property of the 'tls' object?
Below here is my assumption and would ask some of you for correction:

```
const tls: SecureContextOptions = {
  key:    <-- readFile('server.key'),    =  <-- ryans-key.pem   ?
  cert:   <-- readFile('server.crt'),    =  <-- ryans-cert.pem  (or ca-cert.pem)  ?
  ca:     <-- readFile('server.csr'),    =  <-- ryans-csr.pem   ?
}
```

If other steps are required, please explain.

Further, related to this arrangement, which of the five SSL crypto files do I supply to the FTP client, so both, the server and the client are properly configured for a secure FTP communication?

---

I am assuming that this arrangement above, of the crypto files pointing to the properties of the 'tls' object for '#EXPLICIT' connections is practically the same for '#IMPLICIT' connections as well. Please correct me again, if not.

---

Last portion of this configuration is selection of the initial URL header. The ftp-srv documentations offers:

- ftp  - Plain FTP
- ftps - Implicit FTP over TLS

for example:

```
"ftp://0.0.0.0:21"   or
"ftps://0.0.0.0:21"
```

It confuses me on how to programmatically organize the selection between:

- pure FTP  - no security/TLS involved  and,
- FTP with TLS via implicit mode        and,
- FTP with TLS via explicit mode

Comment: You don't need the CSR and it is certainly NOT what to use for CA. I suggest you do try to first learn more about TLS and how certificates are used for authentication, to better understand what all pieces of data mean and how they interact. That investment will help you arrive at your goal faster and should lessen probably of security problems later on.

Comment: What these options mean see [tls.createSecureContext(options)](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options). The `ca` options is obviously used wrong in the example provided - it should be a list of trusted CA for client certificate authentication, not a CSR. If you don't need client certificate authentication the `ca` option is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I figured out and is working.

Few understandings 1st.

- The FTP server is based on node.js and API:  *ftp-srv*
- The FTP client is FileZilla

The standard config (non TLS) works OK on both client and server as per their documentations.

TLS:

*ftp-srv* has two modes:

- ftp   - explicit - recommended (is the same as without TLS)
- ftps  - implicit - (appears to be going out of fashion)

**The TLS - explicit mode - config:**

Generate crypto files:
See [here](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tlsssl-concepts)

```
openssl genrsa -out ryans-key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -sha256 -key ryans-key.pem -out ryans-csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -in ryans-csr.pem -signkey ryans-key.pem -out ryans-cert.pem
cat ryans-cert.pem > ca-cert.pem
```

In your node.js app (the example is for typescript):

```
import * as path from 'path';
import { promises as fsAsync, readFileSync } from "fs";
import { FtpServerOptions, FtpSrv } from 'ftp-srv';


configureTls(): Promise<SecureContextOptions> {

    const CRYPTO_FILES_DIR = // provide your dir where the crypto files are located
    
    const path_key:  string = path.join(CRYPTO_FILES_DIR , 'ryans-key.pem');
    const path_cert: string = path.join(CRYPTO_FILES_DIR , 'ryans-cert.pem');
    const path_ca:   string = path.join(CRYPTO_FILES_DIR , 'ca-cert.pem');
    
    
    const key:  string = await fsAsync.readFile(path_key,  'utf8');
    const cert: string = await fsAsync.readFile(path_cert, 'utf8');
    const ca:   string = await fsAsync.readFile(path_ca,   'utf8');
    
    
    const tls_ConfigOptions: SecureContextOptions = {
        key:  key,
        cert: cert,
        ca:   ca,
    }
    
    return tls_ConfigOptions;
}

                /**
                 * Start the server and listen for requests / connections
                 */
async startFtpServer() {

                // make this configurable ...
    const url: string = 'ftp://127.0.0.1:21'
    
    const ftpSrvCfg: FtpServerOptions = {
        url:      url,
        pasv_url: pasv_url,
        greeting: greeting,
        ...,
        tls = await this.configureTls()
    }
    
    ...
                // create the server instance with all its configs
    const ftpServer: FtpSrv = new FtpSrv(ftpSrvCfg);

                // FTP server is event driven.
                // Here we register the events we need or want to use.
    this.onUserLogin(ftpServer);
    this.onUserDisconnect(ftpServer);
    this.onClientError(ftpServer);

                // start listening for requests
    ftpServer.listen().then( () => {
                // your actions when the server starts ...
        ...
    }


                /**
                 * Occurs on each (user's) login attempt
                 */
    private onUserLogin(ftpServer: FtpSrv) {

        ftpServer.on('login',
                   async ({ connection, username, password }, resolve, reject) => { 
          ....
        }
    }

 



}
```

In the client - FileZilla:

- Click menu - Edit > Settings (Settings box will appear)
- Choose: Connection > SFTP
- Click: Add key file, and navigate to the private key crypto file: ../ryans-key.pem
- Click: OK

Start the server and try to connect. eg:
ftp://127.0.0.1:21

Should work.